# How to update a field programmatically and keep the fields format and array structure?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm trying to update a field with the format full_html. But when I'm updating the field, all the html tags will disappear and the old text is still there in the safe_value. So how can I update the the text in field and keep the existing structure and the html-tags?

I have tried this:

```
$node = $node_load($my_node_id);
$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'My new text.';
```

My field before editing

```
[body] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => <p>My old text.</p>
                        [summary] => 
                        [format] => full_html
                        [safe_value] => <p>My old text.</p>

                        [safe_summary] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

My field after editing

```
[body] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => My new text. //All the html-tags are removed
                        [summary] => 
                        [format] => full_html
                        [safe_value] => <p>My old text.</p> //The old text is still there

                        [safe_summary] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: What's the goal there in changing the field value?

Comment: I want to update the body text for a node programmatically.

Comment: Is that your _exact_ code? This bit should produce an exception: `$node = $node_load($my_node_id);` as I doubt you've defined `$node_load = 'node_load';` anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `node_save()` won't automatically re-load the node so you'll need to do it manually if you want to see the computed field values:

```
$node = node_load($my_node_id);
$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'My new text.';

node_save($node);

// Re-load the node from the db
$node = node_load($node->nid, NULL, TRUE);

// $node->body now has the values you would expect.
```

I just tried that and can confirm I get the same behaviour as you (the safe_value is not updated) if the call to `node_load()` is commented out.

Comment: Thank you Clive. The problem is that the html-tags in the value will be removed. Before I updated the node, the text was wrapped with <p>-tags.

Comment: Yes that's what should happen, you've explicitly written: `$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'My new text.';` _without_ HTML tags. The HTML corrector is run when the content is displayed at the other end. To recreate you can run `$html_body = check_markup($node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], 'full_html');`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the body text for a node programmatically.

If you want to update the body text, probably better to do it once when the node is saved.

for example, one of the node API hooks

- [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)
- [hook_node_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7)

It will be simpler and easier to update there.